# Proof of Triangle Inequality for $d(g; x, y) = \left(|x-y|^4 + g\,| x \times y |^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Tags: geometry, inequality

I am seeking assistance in proving that a function, denoted as $d(g; x, y)$, defined on $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ and parameterized by the non-negative real number $g$, may satisfy the triangle inequality. The function is defined as follows:

\begin{align}
d(g; x, y) &:= \left(|x-y|^4 + g\,| x \times y |^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4}} \\
&= \left( \left((x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2\right)^2 + g\,(x_1\,y_2 - x_2\,y_1)^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{4}}
\end{align}

where $x=(x_1,x_2),\,y=(y_1, y_2)$.

It is noteworthy that when $g=0$, $d(g;x,y)$ coincides with the Euclidean distance.

My ultimate goal is to prove that $d(g; x, y)$ is a distance function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for a certain range of $g$.

While it is trivial that $d(g; x, y)$ is non-degenerate and symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y$, the proof of the triangle inequality is not straightforward. Through numerical calculation, I observed that the triangle inequality seemed to hold in the range $0\leq g \leq 6$.

In other words, the conjecture I wish to prove is as follows: for $0 \leq g \leq 6$, and only in that range,

$$
d(g;x,y)+d(g;y,z)≥d(g;x,z)
$$

holds for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I am looking for guidance and information related to proving this statement.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What is the origin of this exercise ?

Comment: While contemplating the quantification of "similarity" for rectangles, I stumbled upon this by chance.

Consider a rectangle $R(x)$ with vertices at the origin, $x = (x_1, x_2)$, $(x_1, 0)$, and $(0, x_2)$. In this case, if $R(x)$ and $R(y)$ are similar, then $d(g;x,y)$ equals the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$. Otherwise, if $g$ is positive, then $d(g;x,y)$ will be greater than the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the half of the answer : I am going to exhibit a family of counter-examples in the cases $g>6$ where triangular inequality is violated :

$$d(g;x,y)+d(g;y,z) < d(g;x,z)\tag{1}$$

A first remark : function $d$ is rotation-invariant and homogeneous :

$$\begin{cases}d(g;R(u),R(v))&=&d(g;u,v)\\d(g;k.u,k.v)&=&k.d(g;u,v)\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

The first property above allows to assume WLOG that the central point $y$ in (1) can be taken on the real axis (see (4) below).

I have begun by a vast similation making evident that the violation of triangular inequality occurs for any $g > 6$.

For example, in the case $g=6.1$, among $10^5$ random triangles in the unit disk, only 3 of them violate triangle identity, all with the peculiar shape of (almost) flat isosceles triangles :

[image]

I will use complex numbers representation which is slightly more convenient. One can write, by identifying vectors and their affixes (complex numbers) :

$$d(g;a,b)^4=\left(|a-b|^2\right)^2+g.\left(\Im(\overline{a}b)\right)^2\tag{3}$$

Let us consider the three points :

$$x=re^{i \theta}, \ \ \ y=s, \ \ \ z=\overline{x}=re^{-i \theta}\tag{4}$$

(with $s>0$, angles $0<\theta < \pi/2$ will be taken in the vicinity of $\pi/2$ : in this way we have an almost flat isosceles triangle).

Inequality (1) becomes :

$$2 \left((r^2-2rs \cos \theta +s^2)^2+g.(rs \sin \theta)^2\right)^{1/4} < ((2r)^4 \sin(\theta)^4+g.(r^2 \sin(2 \theta))^2)^{1/4}\tag{5}$$

Taking the power $4$ of inequality (5) then dividing by $16$, we get :

$$(r^2-2rs \cos \theta +s^2)^2+g.(rs\sin \theta)^2 < r^4 \sin(\theta)^4 + g \frac{r^4}{16} \sin(2 \theta)^2\tag{6}$$

Now let us make $s$ dependent upon $r$ and $\theta$ :

$$s=\frac{r}{4} \cos \theta \tag{7}$$

Rearranging (6), and simplifying by $r^4$, we get the inequality :
$$(1- \tfrac{7}{16}(\cos \theta)^2)^2+g.\frac{1}{16}(\sin \theta \cos \theta)^2 <  (\sin \theta)^4 + g.\frac{1}{16}(2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^2\tag{8}$$

$$g.\tfrac{3}{16}(\cos \theta)^2 (\sin \theta)^2 > (\sin \theta)^4-(1- \tfrac{7}{16}(\cos \theta)^2)^2 \tag{9}$$

$$g > \underbrace{\tfrac{3}{16} \left(23+\tfrac{9}{(\sin \theta)^2}\right)}_{f(\theta)}\tag{10}$$

Continuous function $f$ is evidently $>6$ with $f(\theta) \rightarrow 6$ when $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$ ; therefore it is always possible for each value $g_0>6$ to find a value $\theta_0$ such that $g_0>f(\theta_0)$, establishing the negation of the triangular inequality for any value of $g$ above $6$.

Comment: I imagine that you have taken norm $L^4$ (with exponents $4$ and $1/4$) in order to be able to combine in a dingle formula the original euclidean distance and the norm of the cross product in order to have the two good behaviors (by rotation and by homothety)...

Comment: I appreciate the excellent results you shared! What particularly interests me is how the peculiar triangle with vertices $re^{i\theta}, r\cos\theta/4$ and $re^{-i\theta}$ sheds light on the derivation of the number 6.

Comment: > I imagine that ... in order to have the two good behaviors (by rotation and by homothety)...

That's correct. I chose the form of $d$ with homogeneity and rotational symmetry in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts.**

Let
$$u := \frac{\Big((x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2\Big)^2 + g(x_1y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2}{\Big((z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2\Big)^2 + g(z_1x_2 - z_2 x_1)^2},$$
and
$$v := \frac{\Big((y_1 - z_1)^2 + (y_2 - z_2)^2\Big)^2 + g(y_1z_2 - y_2 z_1)^2}{\Big((z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2\Big)^2 + g(z_1x_2 - z_2 x_1)^2}.$$

We need to prove that
$$u^{1/4} + v^{1/4} \ge 1.\tag{1}$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $a, b > 0$ and $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\frac{u}{a^3} + 3a + \frac{v}{b^3} + 3b \ge 4.\tag{2}$$
(*Note*: If (2) is true, letting $a = u^{1/4}$ and $b = v^{1/4}$, we have $u^{1/4} + v^{1/4} \ge 1$. )

(2) is written as
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{a^3}\Big((x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2\Big)^2 + \frac{1}{b^3}\Big((y_1 - z_1)^2 + (y_2 - z_2)^2\Big)^2 \\[6pt]
 &\quad - (4 - 3a - 3b)\Big((z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2\Big)^2\\[6pt]
 \ge{}&  g\Big[ (4 - 3a - 3b)(z_1x_2 - z_2 x_1)^2 - \frac{1}{a^3}(x_1y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2 - \frac{1}{b^3}(y_1z_2 - y_2 z_1)^2 \Big]. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
We can prove that $\mathrm{LHS}_{(3)} \ge 0$ (the proof is given at the end). Thus, we only need to prove the case that $\mathrm{RHS}_{(3)}\ge 0$. Thus, it suffices to prove (3) when $g = 6$, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{a^3}\Big((x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2\Big)^2 + \frac{1}{b^3}\Big((y_1 - z_1)^2 + (y_2 - z_2)^2\Big)^2 \\[6pt]
 &\quad - (4 - 3a - 3b)\Big((z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2\Big)^2\\[6pt]
 \ge{}&  6\Big[ (4 - 3a - 3b)(z_1x_2 - z_2 x_1)^2 - \frac{1}{a^3}(x_1y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2 - \frac{1}{b^3}(y_1z_2 - y_2 z_1)^2 \Big]. \tag{4}
\end{align*}

Some numerical experiment supports (4). However, I can not verify (4) using CAS (Computer Algebra System) in a short time (some minutes).

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of $\mathrm{LHS}_{(3)} \ge 0$.*

Let $$p := \frac{\Big((x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2\Big)^2}{\Big((z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2\Big)^2}, \quad q := \frac{\Big((y_1 - z_1)^2 + (y_2 - z_2)^2\Big)^2}{\Big((z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2\Big)^2}.$$
It suffices to prove that $\frac{1}{a^3}p + 3a +  \frac{1}{b^3}q + 3b \ge 4$. By AM-GM, it suffices to prove that $4\sqrt[4]{p} + 4\sqrt[4]{q} \ge 4$ or
$$\sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} + \sqrt{(y_1 - z_1)^2 + (y_2 - z_2)^2} \ge \sqrt{(z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2}$$
which is clearly true. We are done.